# Nested Unordered List in a Parent Ordered List

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure how I would make my nested unordered list not inherit the parent ordered list. As of right now, it's taking all listed items as the background image. I only want my ordered list to show the background image.

```css
div#column1 ol li {
  list-style-image: url(akMLpics/bullets.png);
}

div#column1 ol li>ul {
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

```html
<div id="column1">
  <ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.
      <ul>
        <li>In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li>Etiam quis leo eleifend neque.</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another css rule for the `li` inside the `ul`, which specifies no image, e.g.:

```
div#column1 ol li > ul li {
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

This will override the outer rule.